How to set multiple filters in Python Binwalk API?
I am trying to use the binwalk.scan() function in the Python API and have it functionally similar to the following command line tool call:
binwalk --include 'cpio' --include 'LZMA' filepath

However, I'm struggling to find an equivalent argument syntax that works for the API, the API documentation on the repository page (https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk/blob/master/API.md) does not show any examples of filters being used. This is what I've attempted to use with varying degrees of error:
binwalk.scan(include = 'cpio', include = 'LZMA', '--signature', filepath)

binwalk.scan('--include cpio', '--include LZMA', '--signature', filepath)

binwalk.scan('--include', 'cpio', '--include', 'LZMA', '--signature', filepath)

Some help would be very much appreciated, thanks.
